# parse error on input ‘if’ - why?

Tags: parsing, haskell

I dont know why my programme doesnt work, my ghci shows always the following "parse error on input `if` ".
This is my code:

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

bonuspunkte c d a b =

if (a > 480) then replace a "480" else use a
if (b > 375) then replace b "375" else use b    

if (c == True) && (d == True)   

then (11.5 *(a/480)) + (8.5 *(b/375))
else 0
```

I am also not quite sure about the "replace" operation, my idea was, that if a is bigger then 480, then you should go on working with 480 though. same with b.
I'd be very grateful if somebody could help me.

Comment: It would be nice to know what language this is...

Comment: what lang is this? python?

Comment: sorry its haskell!

Comment: What are `replace` and `use`?

Comment: i thought there where orders. could i replace them with something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a substitute for a tutorial, book, or teacher when beginning to learn a new programming language.

Comment: Aside from all the good advice @ErikR gives, you should reconsider `c` and `d`. Why does `bonuspunkte` need to take two Boolean variables if it's only going to combine them? The simplest change is to make it take just *one*, and require the caller to combine them. But really, I'd skip that part altogether, and let the caller decide whether to apply the bonus.

Comment: @Janet2001 Why did you think that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the value a variable is bound to in Haskell. You can, however, create a new variable names.

```
bonuspunkte a b c d =
  let a' = min 480 a
      b' = min 375 b
  in if c && d then (11.5 *(a'/480)) + (8.5 *(b'/375))
               else 0
```

Note how the variables `a'` and `b'` - not `a` and `b` - are used in the formula in the if-then-else statement.

Also note the indentation. Like Python, Haskell is an indentation significant language.